# Saving rotated image with easeljs?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm loading a bitmap image onto a canvas using easeljs.  I can apply a rotation, and I would like to get the modified dataUrl for that image, showing the rotation.   But rotation seems to be ignored when using `cache` or `getCacheDataURL`?

Sample code -- [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/geosteve/ecwd5vdz/1/)

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

// Create an image.
var image = new Image();
// Since this sample is cross-domain, we must set this flag.
// Note that the origin server supports CORS.
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
image.onload = createImage;
image.src = "http://playpen.createjs.com/CORS/duck.png";

// rotate the image
bmp.rotation = 45;

stage.addChild(bmp);

function createImage() {

  // Update the stage once to show the loaded image (at its native size)
  stage.update();

  // Cache the bitmap. This is necessary to create the cache-canvas.
    bmp.cache(0,0,image.width,image.height);

   // Note that if you update again, it will show the canvas image as blurred.
   //stage.update();

  // Get the cache-canvas's data url.
  var url = bmp.getCacheDataURL();

  // Create a new image with the data url, and add it to the body.
  var img2 = new Image();
  img2.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(img2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is only rotated in its parent context. Rotating it doesn't change the orientation of the source, even if you cache it.

Here is a quick update, where the bitmap is added to a Container, and the container is cached instead of the bmp. Since the bmp is rotated inside the container, it appears as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/ecwd5vdz/2/

```
var cont = new createjs.Container();
cont.addChild(bmp);
//
cont.cache(0,0,image.width,image.height);
```

Hope that helps.